# PHP Laravel. How to store multiple data in one protected variable array and retrieve it

Tags: php, laravel-4

im confused how to retrieve data from protected variable array, im already stored data on that variable but when i used it, it returns null.

```
protected $item_quantity = array();
protected $item_id_pallet_lib = array();

foreach ($itemsUsed as $item) {
$this->item_id_pallet_lib = $this->pallet_assembly_library    
->where('status', '=', 0)                  
->where('item_id', '=', $item->item->id)                                                   ->pluck('item_id');

$this->item_quantity = $this->theoretical
->where('item_id', '=', $this->item_id_pallet_lib)
->pluck('quantity');

}
```

-------------this is my first attempt to retrieve data, but it fails and it returns null or nothing happens to my theoretical table---------

```
foreach ($itemsUsed as $item) {

 $this->theoretical
      ->where('item_id', '=', $this->item_id_pallet_lib)
      ->update(array('quantity' => $this->item_quantity));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `[]` so you can store value at the last of your `$this->item_id_pallet_lib` and `$this->item_quantity` like so:

```
$this->item_id_pallet_lib[]
$this->item_quantity[]
```

Please leave a comment below if it won't work.